# Nodeclipse - org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core not found when installing into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6, jsdt, nodeclipse

Asked by Joshua Richardson as https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/58

After updating eclipse (Helios) recently, I am no longer able to install nodeclipse. I get this error message:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Nodeclipse 0.4.0.201305191444 (org.nodeclipse.feature.group 0.4.0.201305191444)
Missing requirement: Nodeclipse 0.4.0.201305191444 (org.nodeclipse.ui 0.4.0.201305191444) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core 1.1.102' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Nodeclipse 0.4.0.201305191444 (org.nodeclipse.feature.group 0.4.0.201305191444)
To: org.nodeclipse.ui [0.4.0.201305191444]

I tried manually installing JSDT, but that did not solve the problem. I noticed that nodeclipse looks for org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.CORE, but I am unable to find that exact bundle on the helios update page, only this one: org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.FEATURE.FEATURE.GROUP.

It seems that something is changed, and nodeclipse needs to be udpated to allow the new bundle name to fulfill the dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodeclipse is supported version 3.7(Indigo) or above.
Do you need to use Herios?

Comment: Recommendation is actually download latest Eclipse release Kepler

Answer (score 0):

1. Try again after some time
2. As said in [Aptana Studio - can't update to 0.4](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/46) , try install NJSDT or get Enide to install NJSDT
   http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enide-eclipse-nodejs-ide